# Ensuring Accurate Search Results in Shopify Store

Tags: search, filter, shopify, liquid

I'm currently working on the search and discovery app (shopify free app) for my website to ensure that searches remain relevant and confined to appropriate terms. To achieve this, I have set up product boosts and synonyms, which I assign for specific search terms. However, I've noticed that some items are being returned in the search results that aren't related to the assigned synonyms or product boosts.
The problem seems to arise when the search term appears in the item's description, causing unrelated items to be included in the results. This behavior is unintended and needs to be resolved to improve the search accuracy.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue or knows how to address it effectively? I'd greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions to fix this problem and ensure that the search results align correctly with the synonyms and product boosts.
Thank you in advance for your help!